# Credentials rejected by remote desktop to Windows Azure Web Role

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, azure-web-roles

I have created a Cloud project on VS 2012 with .net 4.5. This consists of two web roles, an API and an front end website.

I have followed the instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/gg443832.aspx in order to set up remote desktop, and deployed the service.

When I try to connect (I have double and triple checked the credentials), I get told that 'The credentials that were used to connect to  did not work. Please enter new credentials.

My web roles are both operational, and I can visit them both in the browser.

I have tried waiting a while after deploying for changes to propagate, but this makes no difference. The only thing I can think of is that I have not done anything with certificates as of yet other than download the appropriate bits in order to deploy from visual studio. I can't find any documentation that says I need to though.

I have also tried out adding various domains to the username but nothing works.

Am I missing something, or is there a chance that there is a bug with azure at the moment?

EDIT: Have now tried deleting the cloud project from visual studio, deleting the cloud service in azure and redeploying with only a single web role. Still seeing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checking for completeness,

Did you use the button on the website for your first access?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/04/03/how-to-login-into-windows-azure-virtual-machine-using-remote-desktop.aspx

On the other hand, this is the link that worked for us, it includes how to set up the cert needed too.

http://geekswithblogs.net/MagnusKarlsson/archive/2012/12/03/connect-to-running-web-role-from-remote-desktop-connection-and.aspx

Comment: Yeah I did this, selected the instance clicked connect and downloaded the rdp file provided. The UI has changed since that post but it's the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I had to add the certificate to my local store, THEN set the password in remote desktop settings and redeploy, then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by removing the `<Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />` and `<Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />` lines from the .csdef then removing all references to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess` and `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder` within the .cscfg files. I then was able to deploy and enable remote desktop access from the newer Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

After adding users to the Azure Active Directory Domain, (e.g. smith@mydomain.onmicorosft.com), I tried logging in as one of those users, but got "Your credentials did not work." After some trial and error, I found that I had to add the users (e.g. smith) as local users on the VMs. Once I did that, and assigned, passwords, the users could RDP in.